# android studio image asset

Tags: android, android-studio, изображения, icon

Всем привет,  у меня такая проблема не как не могу сделать прозрачную иконку для android 8 (тестирую на genymotion) на реальном устройстве тоже самое,на android 7 и ниже нормально есть прозрачность в иконке.
В image asset переключал все возможные варианты кнопки галочки результата нет

[image: картинка с прозрачным фоном]

Answer (score 2):

Учитесь рисовать **Adaptive Icons**, в `Android 8.0` без них не получится, документация:

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive.html

> **Caution:** If you don't update your launcher icon with the necessary layers, the icon doesn't look consistent with other icons that the system UI displays, and doesn't support visual effects.